# USB Pendrive not recognizing

Tags: dual-boot, usb, windows-10, usb-drive

While creating a bootable pen drive in `Windows 10` using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) my USB pen drive got corrupted. It cannot be recognized in Windows and Ubuntu machine.
In Ubuntu, while issuing the following command I can see that it is connected but it is not getting mounted.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
```

**Output**

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 28.7 GiB, 30752000000 bytes, 60062500 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal and type `sudo umount /dev/sdb` and type password, then `sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb`

Comment: Hello @ARTube on issuing `sudo umount /dev/sdb` I got error `umount: /dev/sdb: not mounted`. Then on issuing `mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb` I got error `mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/sdb: Permission denied`

Comment: Message of umount is OK and confirms sdb does not contain a partition. Second command should also be preceded by sudo. If second command fails to create a file system, there might be a hardware issue with your USB.